# Null Pointer Exception when printing the checkers board?

Tags: java

I have initialized the board and I am trying to print it but it always gives me null pointer exception. This is my Checkers.java class:

```
 package specialCheckers;
/*There is another class: 
    Checkers which contains a Cell[][] board and a String message. 
    Checkers should have mutators and accessors for these.*/
public class Checkers {
    Cell[][] board;
    String message;
    /**********Setters and getters Started*****/
    public void setBoard(Cell[][] board){
        this.board = board;
    }
    public Cell[][] getBoard(){
        return board;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getMessage(){
        return message;
    }
    /**********Setters and getters Ended*****/

    /*Checkers should also have a public void init() method that sets up the board as you see it in the video below: 
        White cells on the top three rows. 
    The first row starts with an empty cell, then a white, then empty, etc. 
    The second row has that order reversed and the third row is identical to the first one; Red chips go in the bottom 3 rows. 
    The last row starts with a black chip, then empty, then black, etc. 
    The second to last has that order reversed, and the third to last is identical to the last one.*/

    /*********initialization******/
    public void init(){
        board = new Cell[8][8];


        Cell[][] a =
            {
                getEmptyWhiteBlack("EW",0),
                getEmptyWhiteBlack("WE",1),
                getEmptyWhiteBlack("EW",2),
                getEmptyWhiteBlack("EE",3),
                getEmptyWhiteBlack("EE",4),
                getEmptyWhiteBlack("BE",5),
                getEmptyWhiteBlack("EB",6),
                getEmptyWhiteBlack("BE",7)

            };

    }

    private Cell[] getEmptyWhiteBlack(String rowIndicator, int row){
        Cell[] cellArray = new Cell[8];

        if(rowIndicator.equals("EW")) 
            cellArray = getEmptyWhite(row);
        else if(rowIndicator.equals("WE")) 
            cellArray = getWhiteEmpty(row);
        else if(rowIndicator.equals("EE")) 
            cellArray = getEmpty(row);          
        else if(rowIndicator.equals("BE")) 
            cellArray = getBlackEmpty(row);
        else if(rowIndicator.equals("EB")) 
            cellArray = getEmptyBlack(row);

        return cellArray;

    }

    /**
     * Creates empty rows
     *      . . . . . . . .
     *      
     * @param row
     * @return
     */
    private Cell[] getEmpty(int row){
        Cell[] cellArray = new Cell[8];
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            Cell cell = new Cell(row,i);
            cellArray[i] = cell;
        }
        return cellArray;
    }

    /**
     * Creates row of Black & Empty cells
     *      B . B . B . B ,
     * @param row
     * @return
     */
    private Cell[] getBlackEmpty(int row){
        Cell[] cellArray = new Cell[8];
        for(int i = 0; i<8; i++){
            Cell cell = new Black(row,i);
            cellArray[i]=cell;
        }
        return cellArray;
    }
    /*
     * Creates row of Empty & White
     *      . W . W . W . W .
     */
    private Cell[] getEmptyWhite(int row){
        Cell[] cellArray = new Cell[8];
        for(int i = 0; i<8; i++){
            Cell cell;
            if(i%2 == 0){
                cell = new Cell(row,i);
            }
            else{
                cell = new White(row,i);
            }
            cellArray[i]=cell;
        }
        return cellArray;
    }
    /*
     * Creates row of White & Empty
     *       W . W . W . W .
     */

    private Cell[] getWhiteEmpty(int row){
        Cell[] cellArray = new Cell[8];
        for(int i = 0; i<8; i++){
            Cell cell;
            if(i%2 == 0){
                cell = new White(row,i);

            }
            else{
                cell = new Cell(row,i);
            }
            cellArray[i]=cell;
        }
        return cellArray;
    }

    /**
     * Creates row of Black & Empty cells
     *      . B . B . B . B      
     * @param row
     * @return DE
     */
    private Cell[] getEmptyBlack(int row){
        Cell[] cellArray = new Cell[8];
        for(int i = 0; i<8; i++){
            Cell cell;
            if(i%2 == 0){
                cell = new Cell(row, i);
            } else {
                cell = new Black(row,i);
            }
            cellArray[i]=cell;
        }
        return cellArray;
    }

    /*********initialization ended*******/

    /*Checkers has a method public void printBoard() 
    which will print the board with the indices of the columns at the top 
    and the indices of the rows at the left. (See video for reference).*/

    public void printBoard(){
        for(int i = 0; i< 8; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j< 8; j++){
                Cell cell = board[i][j];
                System.out.print(cell.toString());
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

And My Cell Class is here it is the parent class of black and white classes which returns B,W:

```
public class Cell {
public static final String EMPTY=".";

int i;
int j;
String value;

public Cell(int i, int j){
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
    value = EMPTY;
}

public String toString(){
    return value;
}
}
```

Here is My main method.

```
package specialCheckers;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestCheckers {
    public static void main(String [] args){

        Checkers c = new Checkers();
        c.init();
        c.printBoard();
        int[] chips = c.count();
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(chips[0]>0 && chips[1]>0){
            System.out.println("\nYour move? 4 ints: src row, src col, dest row, dest col separated by [SPACE]");
            int srcR = kbd.nextInt();
            int srcC = kbd.nextInt();
            int destR = kbd.nextInt();
            int destC = kbd.nextInt();
            kbd.nextLine();
            c.move(srcR,srcC,destR,destC);
            c.printBoard();
            System.out.println(c.getMessage());
            c.count();
        }
    }
}
```

The Error it give is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at specialCheckers.Checkers.printBoard(Checkers.java:167)
    at specialCheckers.TestCheckers.main(TestCheckers.java:9)
```

Just to add on what line 167 is its the printBoard method

```
public void printBoard(){
    for(int i = 0; i< 8; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j< 8; j++){
            Cell cell = board[i][j];
            System.out.print(cell.toString());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

error is on `System.out.print(cell.toString());`

Comment: Where is the `main` function? Where is the stack trace of the `NullPointerException` these are the important things.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688068/how-to-read-and-understand-the-java-stack-trace
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: who is calling init() method?

Comment: init method is being called in the main method and I have added main and the error which i was getting

Comment: I dont know how you can tell the line number as the code here doesnt gives out line number

Comment: Do you use any IDE or text editor? They will show line numbers.

Comment: @SyedMudabbir Even if we can't get line numbers, we can usually guess if the functions aren't too big.

Comment: Oh I have indicated line number and where compiler is stopping. I use Eclipse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
    board = new Cell[8][8];


    Cell[][] a = { ... };
```

do

```
    Cell[][] a = { ... };

    board = a;
```

The problem is that you are constructing a board but never assigning it to the `board` variable, so you end up with a 8x8 grid of `null` values in `board`.

Comment: When I did that `Array constants can only be used in initializers` error.

Comment: do `board = a` at the end of the method.

Comment: Wow That solved it when I did `board = a;` Thank you so much.

Comment: @Brinnis, quite right.  I forgot about the contextual restrictions on array initializers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
   board =new Cell[8][8];//remove this line
   Cell[][] a = { ... }
   //just assign it to your board
   board = a;
```