# using autocomplete value to get new value from sqlite and populate edittext

Tags: php, android, sqlite, autocomplete

I have a autocomplete code that picks and displays options from the sqlite db based on the first letter/character entered. I want, when the right option is selected from list of displayed options, the value to be passed to a query and the result passed to an edittext field. The autocomplete change listener has a method

```
afterTextChanged(Editable s)
```

but it only seemingly accepts one character (not whole string). Any advice on how I can go about this? or an online resource to do further reading?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `AutoCompleteTextView` for this purpose.

I'll suggest you should take a look at follow links.

[Link 1](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-autocompletetextview.html) -  Android AutoCompleteTextView CursorAdapter using SQLite Database and ArrayAdapter

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927747/android-getting-strings-from-sqlite-database-to-autocompletetextview) - Android getting strings from sqlite database to autocompletetextview

[Link 3](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/11/android-autocompletetextview-example-sqlite-database.html) - Android AutocompleteTextView with Database Data as Suggestions