# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException Java GUI Error

Tags: java, user-interface, nullpointerexception

I am trying to design a calculator in java. My code isn't finished but I have designed a GUI, which works except for when i try to actually calculate the result. When i press "=" on my calculator i receive the above error. Here is my code:

**Problem fixed**

I know it is a lot of code so I am sorry for that, and I also realize there may be other errors in there, as I am fairly new to Java, I am just very stuck with the error I'm getting at the moment and have no clue how to fix it, thanks for any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're never initializing `calcOperands` - so on line 60, when you use:

```
calcOperands.add(operand);
```

... `calcOperands` is still null, causing the exception. It looks like you have the same problem for your other `ArrayList` variables. You can just create a new list as part of the declaration - and I'd also change the variables themselves to just `List<E>`, like this:

```
private final List<Double> calcOperands = new ArrayList<Double>();
private final List<String> calcOperators = new ArrayList<String>();
private final String stringInput;
private final List<Integer> priorityList = new ArrayList<String>();
private String[] splitString;
```

I've made most of the variables final too, as a matter of course. You might want to consider whether you really want `splitString` to be mutable, only set if you call `checkInput`...

(I haven't looked at the rest of your code.)

Besides just fixing these problems, you should take a step back and think about the diagnostics side of things. Which bit were you stuck on when trying to find the problem? Had you looked at the stack trace and pinpointed the problem to `StringCalculator.java` line 60? Do you understand what `NullPointerException` means? (And if not, had you tried to find out?) Now that you know the actual answer, it's worth thinking about how you could have reached it yourself - diagnosing issues is an important part of software development.

Comment: +1 appending this previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12688109/2415194) to learn how to read and understand java stacktrace

Comment: Thanks a lot sorted it, yeah i could see that it occurred at line 60 but couldn't see why, hence why i found it so frustrating. Thanks for the help.