# How to add data to JTable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I'm still a little new to Java and a complete noob to Gui's. I can't for the life of me figure out how to add the data from my String array into the Jtable. I tried to read the docs on oracle but it was not making sense to me for my particular situation. If you guys could please point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. Also I'm retrieving my array data from a file. Not sure if that makes a difference.

```
    public class TemplateGui extends JFrame {
    private JTable tableHotelSecurity, securityFlagsTable;
    private final ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    private JTextField textField;
    private static String [] sortedRoles_Flags,finalFlagsArr,finalHSArr;
    private static String finalFlags="",finalHS="",column;


    public TemplateGui(){

        super("Galaxy Template Generator V1.0");
        getContentPane().setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(51, 51, 51));

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 170, 189, 186);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane_1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane_1.setBounds(222, 170, 372, 186);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane_1);

        //radio buttons
        JRadioButton rdbtnNewRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Central User ");
        rdbtnNewRadioButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        rdbtnNewRadioButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        buttonGroup.add(rdbtnNewRadioButton);
        rdbtnNewRadioButton.setBounds(222, 75, 127, 36);
        getContentPane().add(rdbtnNewRadioButton);

        final JRadioButton rdbtnPropertyUser = new JRadioButton("Property User");
        rdbtnPropertyUser.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        rdbtnPropertyUser.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        buttonGroup.add(rdbtnPropertyUser);
        rdbtnPropertyUser.setBounds(222, 38, 127, 34);
        getContentPane().add(rdbtnPropertyUser);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        textField.setBounds(10, 35, 53, 34);
        getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblHotelSecurity = new JLabel("Hotel Security (H S)");
        lblHotelSecurity.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblHotelSecurity.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        lblHotelSecurity.setBounds(10, 144, 189, 23);
        lblHotelSecurity.setBackground(new Color(204, 204, 204));
        lblHotelSecurity.setOpaque(true);
        getContentPane().add(lblHotelSecurity);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Security Flags (S F)");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        label.setBounds(222, 144, 372, 23);
        label.setBackground(new Color(204, 204, 204));
        label.setOpaque(true);
        getContentPane().add(label);

        JLabel lblEnterTemplateCode = new JLabel("ENTER TEMPLATE CODE");
        lblEnterTemplateCode.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        lblEnterTemplateCode.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblEnterTemplateCode.setBounds(10, 9, 175, 23);
        getContentPane().add(lblEnterTemplateCode);

        JLabel lblSelectUserRole = new JLabel("SELECT USER ROLE LEVEL");
        lblSelectUserRole.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        lblSelectUserRole.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblSelectUserRole.setBounds(222, 13, 195, 14);
        getContentPane().add(lblSelectUserRole);

        //Submit button action
        Button button = new Button("Generate Template");
        button.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 12));
        button.setBackground(new Color(102, 255, 102));
        button.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        button.setBounds(467, 83, 127, 41);
        getContentPane().add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                Query excell = new Query();
                //get template text
                String template = textField.getText().toUpperCase();
                System.out.println(template);

                if(rdbtnPropertyUser.isSelected()){
                    try {
                    //property user was selected
                        excell.runProcess(1);
                        System.out.println("you selected Property user");
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        System.out.println("Error occured on line 70 Interface Class");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    try {
                    //Central User was selected 
                        excell.runProcess(2);
                        System.out.println("you selected central user");
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        System.out.println("Error occured on line 79 Interface Class");
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("NOW WERE HERE");
                //get static variables from Excel Query 
                for(int i = 0; i< Query.sortedGF.length; i++)
                {
                    if(Query.sortedGF[i].contains(template)){
                         sortedRoles_Flags  =Query.sortedGF[i].split(" ");
                         System.out.println("THIS RAN"+" :"+i); 
                         break;
                    }

                }
                System.out.println("NOW WERE HERE 103 " +Query.securityFlags.length);
                //add data to table
                int j=0;
                int sizeOfFlags = Query.securityFlags.length;
                System.out.println("Size Of the Flags is:"+" "+sizeOfFlags);
                System.out.println("Size Of the Flags is:"+" "+sortedRoles_Flags.length);

                //Add HS to FinalHS Variable only if Yes
                for(int i=0;i< sortedRoles_Flags.length-sizeOfFlags;i++)
                {
                    if(sortedRoles_Flags[i].matches("Y|y|Y\\?|\\?Y|y\\?|\\?y"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Hotel security:"+" "+sortedRoles_Flags[i]+" HS Added: "+Query.hotelSecurity[i]);
                            finalHS += Query.hotelSecurity[i]+" ";
                            System.out.println("Hotel security:"+" "+finalHS);
                        }
                }

                //add Security Flags to Final Flags
                for(int i=(sortedRoles_Flags.length-sizeOfFlags);i< sortedRoles_Flags.length;i++)
                {                   
                        finalFlags += Query.securityFlags[j]+": "+ sortedRoles_Flags[i]+" + ";
                        j++;
                }

                //Leave open just incase they would prefer a text file for template in which case we just write it
                System.out.println(finalFlags);

                System.out.println(finalHS);

                //Convert to String Arrays in order to add to our JTable
                finalFlagsArr= finalFlags.split("\\+");
                finalHSArr = finalHS.split(" ");



            }
        });
        //content to be in the table 
                DefaultTableModel modelH = new DefaultTableModel();
                tableHotelSecurity = new JTable(modelH);
                scrollPane.setViewportView(tableHotelSecurity);

                DefaultTableModel modelS = new DefaultTableModel();
                securityFlagsTable = new JTable(modelS);
                scrollPane_1.setViewportView(securityFlagsTable);

    }

}
```

Comment: Don't do error messages like `System.out.println("Error occured on line 79 Interface Class");`. That's just ridiculous, especially considering how the line numbers will change. Use `e.printStackTrace();` instead, you'll get the actual exception type too.

Comment: Thats just something I do because the stack trace bothers me. I revert back when I clean up my code. There's a lot of code print statements for debugging in there sorry about that.

Comment: *"Thats just something I do because the stack trace bothers me."* ..are you sure you're cut out for programming?  Seriously, someone who is 'bothered' by stack traces just does not strike me as a person who could become an effective programmer.

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Comment: This application is something I'm creating for personal use because there are task for creating accounts that are tedious. I'm making this to make my life easier. I don't think my debugging method is relevant to the question that I am asking. I never use Gui's so if you guys could shed light on the question that I'm asking I would appreciate it.

Comment: Learning to read a [stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12688068/230513) is foundational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

The main idea is, that swing is built on the principles of MVC architecture. What that means for you is that the component that is responsible for displaying the table (JTable), and the component that knows what is in the table (TableModel) are separated. You somehow need to pass the model to the table. You can either use the DefaultTableModel, which is what you did, or define your own model that implements the interface TableModel.
For the first, you need to pass in an array to the constructor of DefaultTableModel.
For the latter you need to implement methods that - among others - query data at certain positions, but this is worth considering only if the out of the box stuff does not do it for you.

On a side note about error messages: if you are serious about programming, don't get used to bad patterns. They might seem easier now, but they are ill-advised for a reason. They usually don't scale well from a hello-world size project to a full blown project developed by multiple people. Stacktrace is your friend. Use a logger instead of sysout. It will be easier for you in the long run if you get used to good practices now.

Comment: I have no idea why I couldn't find hat section on oracle got my answer. What's a logger?

Comment: A logger can write messages at various logging levels (ie.: debug, warning, info - terminology may differ). You can specify (even from a configuration file, without having to modify your code) what type of messages you want to get - some might be interesting only when you are debugging, some might be there so that you know in what state your program is in. Another benefit is that you can configure where the log messages are printed: into a file, on the console, nowhere, and even better, you can control from configuration where each logger instance outputs.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.slf4j.org/, http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/, or just google java loggers :)

Comment: I really appreciate it man ! Thanks sounds like exactly what I need =D