# Can't figure out the error in this javaFXML file

Tags: java, javafx, error-handling, compiler-errors, fxml

So i have an FXML project with a few stuff in it, and to test out a function in the UI i'm making i decided to create a 2nd main function named Main2 that loads up an FXML named HomePage (controller code at the bottom). so here's main2 first

```
package javafxapplication4;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main2 extends Application  {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("HomePage.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,750,500);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);   
    }
}
```

and here is HomePage controller

```
package javafxapplication4;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;

import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class HomePageController implements Initializable {

    @FXML AnchorPane holderPane;
   
    AnchorPane home;
    
    
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        createPage();
        
    }    
        private void setNode(Node node){
            holderPane.getChildren().clear();
            holderPane.getChildren().add((Node)node);
            
            FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(1500));
            ft.setNode(node);
            ft.setFromValue(0.1);
            ft.setToValue(1);
            ft.setCycleCount(1);
            ft.setAutoReverse(false);
            ft.play();
            
        }
    private void createPage() {
        try {
            home = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("HOME.fxml"));
            setNode(home);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
    
    }
    
}
```

HOME.fxml is another FXML file that's supposed to load up on an anchor pane that's inside HomePage
HOME.fxml has an empty controller btw

```
package javafxapplication4;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

public class HOMEController implements Initializable {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {


    }    
    
}
```

now for some reason i'm getting an error when i try to run the Main2 File on it's own and honestly i'm kind of stuck and wondering if someone can be able to help me fix this error
[image]

Here's the FXML for HomePage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="750.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication4.HomePageController">
   <children>
      <Separator layoutX="147.0" layoutY="8.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="498.0" prefWidth="0.0" />
      <Separator layoutX="147.0" layoutY="37.0" prefHeight="1.0" prefWidth="600.0" />
      <Pane layoutY="-2.0" prefHeight="507.0" prefWidth="147.0" style="-fx-background-color: #36394B;">
         <children>
            <ImageView fitHeight="57.0" fitWidth="62.0" layoutX="45.0" layoutY="14.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@Resources/cashier-pngrepo-com.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <Label layoutY="71.0" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="147.0" text="Welcome to the Register" textFill="#bcb5b5" underline="true" />
            <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="145.0" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="147.0" text="Dashboard" textFill="#d3d3d3">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="3.0" layoutY="128.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="147.0" text="~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" textFill="WHITE" />
            <JFXButton layoutX="14.0" layoutY="207.0" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="119.0" text="Products" textFill="#d3d0d0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXButton layoutX="14.0" layoutY="251.0" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="Add Products" textFill="#d3d0d0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="16.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXButton layoutX="14.0" layoutY="301.0" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="119.0" text="History" textFill="#d3d0d0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
            <Label layoutX="4.0" layoutY="389.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="147.0" text="~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" textFill="WHITE" />
            <JFXButton layoutX="11.0" layoutY="416.0" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="127.0" style="-fx-border-color: WHITE;" text="CONTACT US" textFill="#d3cdcd">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="16.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
            <Label layoutX="119.0" layoutY="221.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="16.0" style="-fx-background-color: #00dbff;" text="0" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </Pane>
      <Label contentDisplay="GRAPHIC_ONLY" layoutX="709.0" layoutY="8.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="41.0">
         <graphic>
            <ImageView fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="29.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@Resources/menu.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </graphic>
      </Label>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="holderPane" layoutX="147.0" layoutY="40.0" prefHeight="464.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <children>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="444.0" prefWidth="593.0">
               <children>
                  <Pane layoutX="34.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                  <Pane layoutX="327.0" layoutY="222.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                  <Pane layoutX="34.0" layoutY="222.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                  <Pane layoutX="327.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <Label layoutX="351.0" layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="157.0" text="WELCOME">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="29.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and HOME's FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="444.0" prefWidth="593.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" fx:controller="javafxapplication4.HOMEController">
   <children>
      <JFXButton alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" contentDisplay="TOP" layoutX="70.0" layoutY="41.0" prefHeight="137.0" prefWidth="192.0" style="-fx-background-color: #36394B;" text="Meat" textFill="#eeeeee">
         <graphic>
            <ImageView fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="117.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@Resources/kisspng-sausage-beefsteak-ribs-rib-eye-steak-cooked-meat-5a79790a9a1f69.8269101615179102826313.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </graphic>
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
         </font>
      </JFXButton>
      <JFXButton alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" contentDisplay="TOP" layoutX="341.0" layoutY="41.0" prefHeight="140.0" prefWidth="192.0" style="-fx-background-color: #36394B;" text="Sea food" textFill="WHITE">
         <graphic>
            <ImageView fitHeight="105.0" fitWidth="125.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@Resources/kisspng-seafood-lobster-crab-boston-lobster-meal-5a7c6edbb6d749.9654965815181042837489.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </graphic>
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
         </font>
      </JFXButton>
      <JFXButton alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" contentDisplay="TOP" layoutX="70.0" layoutY="222.0" prefHeight="137.0" prefWidth="192.0" style="-fx-background-color: #36394B;" text="Bakery" textFill="WHITE">
         <graphic>
            <ImageView fitHeight="106.0" fitWidth="131.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@Resources/kisspng-croissant-coffee-danish-pastry-milk-pain-au-chocol-a-pile-of-croissants-5a807d9ad35bb2.7678630115183702028657.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </graphic>
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
         </font>
      </JFXButton>
      <JFXButton alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" contentDisplay="TOP" layoutX="341.0" layoutY="223.0" prefHeight="140.0" prefWidth="192.0" style="-fx-background-color: #36394B;" text="Herbs" textFill="WHITE">
         <graphic>
            <ImageView fitHeight="132.0" fitWidth="144.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@Resources/kisspng-tea-herb-greek-cuisine-health-spice-herbs-png-photo-5a74a9173ea726.1607035815175949032566.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </graphic>
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
         </font>
      </JFXButton>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Also check out [How to read and understand a Java stacktrace.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688068/how-to-read-and-understand-the-java-stack-trace)

Comment: no screenshots of text please

Comment: Do you have an `fx:id="holderPane"` attribute for an `AnchorPane` element in your FXML file?

Comment: Yea i do. on the anchor pane inside the main anchor pane of HomePage.fxml

Comment: @Zephyr it actually didn't seem to help. i understand there's a NullPointerException but i still can't seem to understand where

Comment: The stack trace tells you exactly where the NPE is coming from...

Comment: I do understand but i still don't know how to fix it i'm sorry.. @Zephyr